# My file can compile but I get "no such file or directory" when I try to run it

Tags: c++, pthreads

I figured that the problem was that I was not using ./a.out instead of ./filename, but that wasn't the case.

This is how I compile my program:

```
g++ -o -Wall -pthread filename.cpp
```

Running:

```
./filename
```

I figured that running pthread programs would be different than running a standard c++ program, but that wasn't the case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h> 

struct argStruct {
    int arg1;
    int arg2;

};

void *sum(void *arguments) {
    struct argStruct *args = (struct argStruct *)arguments;

    int a =  args -> arg1;
    int b =  args -> arg2;
    int c = a + b;
    printf("%d + %d = %d ",a,b,c);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main() {

    pthread_t thr1, thr2;
    struct argStruct args;
    args.arg1 = 3;
    args.arg2 = 10;

    int t1, t2;

    pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &sum, (void *)&args);

    pthread_create(&thr2, NULL, &sum, (void *)&args);


    pthread_join(thr1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thr2, NULL);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

Comment: Try this: `./-Wall`

Comment: Or use `g++ -Wall -pthread -o filename filename.cpp`

Comment: That worked. Do you know of any reason why the file couldn't be found when I tried to compile it originally?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @JohnStone What file? If you mean a file called "filename" -- why would you expect there to be one?

Comment: `g++ -o -Wall` writes the output to a file named `-Wall`.

Comment: Might be worth formally answering this one @HenriMenke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By calling

```bash
g++ -o -Wall -pthread filename.cpp
```

You instruct the compiler to write the result to a file named `-Wall`.

You therefore want to use one of these

```bash
g++ -Wall -pthread filename.cpp
g++ -Wall -pthread -o filename filename.cpp
```

The first writes the result to `a.out`, the second to `filename`.  (Also it enables the warnings)